I am attempting to make use of docker swarm to join my 2 computers for a project and I keep getting the same exception
The exception I am getting is as follows:
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 100.107.116.95:2377: connect: connection refused"
I saw the other post discussing this same problem and I have tried each solution that was presented but none of them worked for me.
PC 1 (Windows - Master):
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168...
PC 2 (Windows): docker swarm join --token  <192.168...>
I have my firewall off on both computers and I am at a loss whether I have skipped a step.

are you connecting on 100.107.116.95 or on 192.168... ?
